# How can I send and update reactive values from within a R Shiny module?

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to write a module that gets a reactive dataframe as an input and allows the user to manipulate it (for the sake of the Minimal Reproducible Example, to add to the table a single row)

Initially, the data that being passed to the module from the main app is some default dataframe (hard coded in the MRE), so the module is always initiated with data.

In addition, I also want to allow the user to manipulate that data from outside the module (for the sake of the MRE, override the dataset with a different, hard-coded dataset).

**I cannot make both functionalities in the MRE to work at the same time. At the moment, the update from main app works, but the update from within the module won't work. I found some solutions that would enable the opposite situation.**

- when trying to add row: no response and no error.

Note 1: The use of modules in the MRE is artificial and not really needed, but it is very much needed in the real app.

Note2: returning a new data frame instead of updating it is not ideal in my case as I would want to allow the user other manipulations, and only after all changes are done, to return the the new data frame.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

DEFAULT_DATA <- tribble(
  ~letter, ~number,
  "A",   1,
  "B",   2,
)



changeDataUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    tableOutput(ns("tbl"))
    ,br()
    ,actionButton(ns("add_row"), 'Add Row')
  )
}


changeDataServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      observeEvent(input$add_row, {
        data <- data() %>% add_row(letter = "C", number = 3)
      })

      output$tbl <- renderTable(data())
    }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MRE App")
  ,fluidRow(column(6, actionButton("change_dataset", "Change Dataset")))
  ,fluidRow(column(6, changeDataUI("some_id")))
)



server <- function(input, output) {

  glob_rvs <- reactiveValues(data = DEFAULT_DATA)

  observeEvent(input$change_dataset, {
    glob_rvs$data <- tribble(
      ~letter, ~number,
      "D",   4,
      "E",   5,
    )
  })

  changeDataServer(id = "some_id", data = reactive(glob_rvs$data))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: As it seems you are having two separate problems, I would recommend splitting this into two separate stackoverflow questions: one about passing reactives to modules and one about the uploading. There could be more people able to help with the upload issue that might not be familiar with modules, or vice versa. I know I work much more with modules than I do with uploads in Shiny

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense. The thing is, I can more or less solve each of these problems as a stand a lone problem, but none of these solution allow the other functionality. This is why I thought it might be a more general/fundamental thing that I'm missing....

Comment: the upload part in the MRE might be simplified: any change of the reactive value that is sent to the module, from within the main app would serve the same goal. will try to construct a better MRE

Comment: Looking closer, your upload issue is a typo in the input ID....

Comment: thank you @Marcus. I edited the example. no uploading now. Just 2 buttons, both trying to update the same reactive value, one from the main app and one from the module. fixed the typo as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With R, you typically want your modules to act as functional as possible. This, as you point out allows you to better reason about your app. I would have your module return the rows to be added and then have your top level app append them. Otherwise you module is essentially causing side effects. Also, this way your top level app (or another module) could coordinate multiple manipulations. The module could still show the data

Example implementation for module server:

```r
changeDataServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      additionalRows <- reactiveVal()
      
      observeEvent(input$change, {
        additionalRows(
          data.frame(letter = sample(letters, 1) , number = runif(1, 0, 10))
        )
      })
      
      output$tbl <- renderTable(data())
      
      # return reactive with additional rows to allow to be merged at top level
      additionalRows
    }
  )
}
```

Then update the `server` (also changed the input for the upload handler to match the UI (`input$uploaded_data` not `input$uploaded_scheme`)

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  glob_rvs <- reactiveValues(data = DEFAULT_DATA)
  
  observeEvent(input$uploaded_data, {
    uploaded_data <- read_csv(input$uploaded_data$datapath)
    glob_rvs$data <- uploaded_data
  })
  
  newRows <- changeDataServer(id = "some_id", data = reactive(glob_rvs$data))
  
  observe({
    glob_rvs$data <- bind_rows(glob_rvs$data, newRows())
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(newRows())
  
}
```

Comment: That works very well and also the functional approach here is desired, I just couldn't figure it out myself... Thanks for the useful tip!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is to pass you reactiveValues object as an argument of your module server.

I advise you read [this article](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/communication-between-modules-and-its-whims/) about how to communicate data between modules

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

DEFAULT_DATA <- tribble(
  ~letter, ~number,
  "A",   1,
  "B",   2,
)

changeDataUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    tableOutput(ns("tbl"))
    ,br()
    ,actionButton(ns("change"), 'Add Row')
  )
}

changeDataServer <- function(id, glob_rvs) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      observeEvent(input$change, {
        print(glob_rvs$data)
        glob_rvs$data <- glob_rvs$data %>% add_row(letter = "C", number = 3)
      })
      
      output$tbl <- renderTable(glob_rvs$data)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MRE App")
  ,fluidRow(column(6, 
                   fileInput("uploaded_data", 
                             "would ypu like to upload your own data?",
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             accept = c(".csv"))))
  ,fluidRow(column(6, changeDataUI("some_id")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  glob_rvs <- reactiveValues(data = DEFAULT_DATA)
  
  observeEvent(input$uploaded_data, {
    uploaded_data <- read_csv(input$uploaded_scheme$datapath)
    glob_rvs$data <- uploaded_data
  })
  
  changeDataServer(id = "some_id", glob_rvs = glob_rvs)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you @gdevaux. I would want to refrain from passing my entire list of reactive values to a module that is only allowed to change one of them. That seems like something with potential to many future bugs...

Comment: Just create another reactiveValues juste for passing this data

Comment: Ok, that's one approach. But if the module is recreated many times it would also mean to maintain many lists, each holding one reactive value.

Btw, your solution indeed solves the adding row functionality, but not the upload functionality. I came across some solutions that solved one of these problems but not both...
thanks again, will read the reference you attached.

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution by @Marcus, here is a working version that is consistent with the last version of post:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

DEFAULT_DATA <- tribble(
  ~letter, ~number,
  "A",   1,
  "B",   2,
)



changeDataUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    tableOutput(ns("tbl"))
    ,br()
    ,actionButton(ns("add_row"), 'Add Row')
  )
}



changeDataServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      additionalRows <- reactiveVal()
      
      observeEvent(input$add_row, {
        additionalRows(
          data.frame(letter = sample(letters, 1) , number = runif(1, 0, 10))
        )
      })
      
      output$tbl <- renderTable(data())
      
      # return reactive with additional rows to allow to be merged at top level
      additionalRows
    }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MRE App")
  ,fluidRow(column(6, actionButton("change_dataset", "Change Dataset")))
  ,fluidRow(column(6, changeDataUI("some_id")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  glob_rvs <- reactiveValues(data = DEFAULT_DATA)
  
  observeEvent(input$change_dataset, {
    glob_rvs$data <- tribble(
      ~letter, ~number,
      "D",   4,
      "E",   5,
    )
  })
  
  newRows <- changeDataServer(id = "some_id", data = reactive(glob_rvs$data))
  
  observe({
    glob_rvs$data <- bind_rows(glob_rvs$data, newRows())
  }) %>%
    bindEvent(newRows())
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```