# Get an input from a button in table from modules in R

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm starting to work with modules using Rhino, and I want to get the input from a button that is inside a table when it is clicked.

**This is the module that creates the table and generate HTML buttons for each line item.**

```
# app/logic/fluxogramaProcesso.R

box::use(
    glue[glue],
    dplyr[filter, select, mutate],
    reactable[reactable, colDef],
    DBI[dbConnect, dbDisconnect, dbGetQuery],
)

box::use(
    app/logic/connectdb,
    app/logic/funcTrim
)

#' @export
cadastroProdutos <- function() {
    con <- connectdb$create_con()
    
    produtos_query <- glue("SELECT ITEM_CODE FROM TABLE")
    
    produtos_tbl <- dbGetQuery(con, produtos_query) |>
        funcTrim$trimDataChar() |>
        as.data.frame() |>
        mutate(
            view_item = glue::glue('<button class="btn" id="vw_item" onclick="Shiny.onInputChange(\'vw_item\', \'{ITEM_CODE}\')"> <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i> </button>')
        ) |>
        reactable(
            columns = list(
                view_item = colDef(html = TRUE)
            )
        )
    
    dbDisconnect(con)
    
    return(produtos_tbl)
}
```

**The table generated by this module, goes to a module that generate the server and ui of this table.
**

```
# app/view/table.R

box::use(
    reactable[reactableOutput, renderReactable],
    shiny[moduleServer, NS, observeEvent],
)

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    reactableOutput(ns("table"))
}


#' @export
server <- function(id, data) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
        output$table <- renderReactable({
            data()
        })
    })
}
```

And then finnaly go to my main.R

```
# app/main.R

box::use(
    shiny[bootstrapPage, moduleServer, NS, reactive, icon, textInput, renderText, observeEvent, showModal, modalDialog],
    shinydashboard[dashboardPage, dashboardHeader, dashboardBody, dashboardSidebar, sidebarMenu, menuItem, tabItems, tabItem],
)

box::use(
    app/view/table,
    app/view/dataTable,
    app/logic/dataProduct,
    app/logic/fluxogramaProcesso,
    app/logic/cadastroProdutos,
)

#' @export
ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        
        dashboardSidebar(
            sidebarMenu(
                menuItem("Fluxograma  de Processos", 
                         tabName = "fluxproc",
                         icon = icon("sitemap"))
            )
        ),
        
        dashboardBody(
            tabItems(
                tabItem(tabName  = "fluxproc",
          
                        table$ui(ns("cadastroProd"))
                        )
            )
        )
    )
}

#' @export
server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        
        dataProdutos <- reactive(cadastroProdutos$cadastroProdutos())
        table$server("cadastroProd", dataProdutos)
        
        observeEvent(input$vw_item, {
            showModal(
                modalDialog(
                    h2("IT WORKS !!!!")
                )
            )
        }
        )
    })
}
```

I would like to when the button on the table was clicked it generates for example a showModal. I couldn't retrieve the input from the button.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your module server function returns `NULL` and you don't monitor the return value of the instance of the module server that you create in your main server.  You need to fix both those things.  See Section 19.3 of [this page](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html) for more information.  And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75031336/how-can-i-send-and-update-reactive-values-from-within-a-r-shiny-module) for a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Rhino and box so I'm not sure of me.

This is a server module:

```r
server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        
        dataProdutos <- reactive(cadastroProdutos$cadastroProdutos())
        table$server("cadastroProd", dataProdutos)
        
        observeEvent(input$vw_item, {
            showModal(
                modalDialog(
                    h2("IT WORKS !!!!")
                )
            )
        }
        )
    })
}
```

Therefore, if I'm not mistaken, the observer will actually listen to `input[[ns("vw_item")]]` and then the button click will never be detected because it triggers `Shiny.onInputChange("vw_item"`.

So I would try:

```r
cadastroProdutos <- function(ns) { # add ns argument
    con <- connectdb$create_con()
    
    produtos_query <- glue("SELECT ITEM_CODE FROM TABLE")
    
    ID <- ns("vw_item") # the name of the Shiny value sent on click

    produtos_tbl <- dbGetQuery(con, produtos_query) |>
        funcTrim$trimDataChar() |>
        as.data.frame() |>
        mutate( # send input[[ID]] on click
            view_item = glue::glue('<button class="btn" id="vw_item" onclick="Shiny.onInputChange(\'{ID}\', \'{ITEM_CODE}\')"> <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i> </button>')
        ) |>
        reactable(
            columns = list(
                view_item = colDef(html = TRUE)
            )
        )
    
    dbDisconnect(con)
    
    return(produtos_tbl)
}
```

and:

```r
server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns
        
        dataProdutos <- reactive(cadastroProdutos$cadastroProdutos(ns)) # added ns
        table$server("cadastroProd", dataProdutos)
        
        observeEvent(input$vw_item, {
            showModal(
                modalDialog(
                    h2("IT WORKS !!!!")
                )
            )
        }
        )
    })
}
```

---

## Edit: possible alternative

A possible alternative is to use the **reactable.extras** package to make the buttons. Unfortunately, I have not been able to render an icon inside these buttons (but I opened an issue on the **reactable.extras** Github repo about this problem).

```r
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(reactable.extras)

df <- MASS::Cars93[, 1:4]
df$view_item <- "click"

mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  reactableOutput(ns("table"))
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      
      output$table <- renderReactable({
        reactable(
          df,
          columns = list(
            view_item = colDef(
              cell = button_extra(id = ns("button"), class = "button-extra")
            )
          )
        )
      })
      
      item <- eventReactive(input$button, {
        df$Manufacturer[input$button$row]
      })
      
      return(item)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactable_extras_dependency(),
  mod_ui("x")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  x <- mod_server("x")
  
  observe({
    print(x())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you Stéphane, the first alternative worked! Thank you a lot!